# Could hypothetical or possibility

Tags: grammar

I cannot distinguish if "***could***" in the following sentences shows "*possibility*" or "*hypothetical situation*".

> A study published last week in the journal Cell found that antibodies
> in llamas’ blood could offer a defense against the coronavirus. The
> hope is that the llama antibodies could help protect humans who have
> not been infected.

I would be happy to receive your replies.

Comment: Where have you found this sentence. Can you provide a link?

Comment: The sentence implies that this is a genuine possibility which scientists are investigating, not just a hypothesis.

Comment: @KateBunting: I think what the OP is asking is whether ***could*** means ***is able to*** or ***might be able to*** in the cited context. Clearly, it's the latter in this *exact* context, but if the former sense was intended, we could perhaps in principle convey that by using ***can*** rather than ***could***. But it would be safer to spell it out with ***is able to*** to avoid possible misinterpretation.

Comment: @KateBunting: I think "could" here is not hypothesis at all.

Comment: That is what I said.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica: I think "could" here is not hypothesis at all because of the context. Did I get it right? Do you think if we could use "can" to convey that the antibodies in llamas' blood will offer a possibility for a defense against the Coronavirus? What would be the difference in meaning with "is able to"?

Comment: @ Kate Bunting: Do you think if we could use "can" to convey that the antibodies in llamas' blood will offer a possibility for a defense against the Coronavirus? What would be the difference in meaning with "is able to"?

Comment: I think it's distractingly irrelevant to be referring to an actual "hypothesis" here. The primary distinction is between whether *A **actually does** B* (more precisely, *actually does **have that capability***), or *A **might possibly** do B*. Within that second alternative, it's ambiguous (without further context) whether that "lack of certainty" is because (1) - we don't know for sure whether A does B at all, or (2) - although we know that A *sometimes* does B, we don't necessarily know whether it will do so ***in any given specific case***.